# Getting type error of Binding element children implicitly of any

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am converting a jsx code to typescript in which i have faced an error like below

Binding element 'children' implicitly has an any type

My Code in jsx is as below

```
const GoogleMap = ({ children, ...props }) => (
  <div style={{ height: '80vh', width: '100%' }}>
    <GoogleMapReact
      bootstrapURLKeys={{
        key: environment.googleApiKey,
      }}
      {...props}
    >
      {children}
    </GoogleMapReact>
  </div>
);

GoogleMap.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.node,
    PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.node),
  ]),
};

GoogleMap.defaultProps = {
  children: null,
};

export default GoogleMap;
```

The above code which is now converted to typescript as below

```
const GoogleMap = ({ children, ...props }) => (
  <div style={{ height: '80vh', width: '100%' }}>
    <GoogleMapReact
      bootstrapURLKeys={{
        key: environment.googleApiKey,
      }}
      {...props}
    >
      {children}
    </GoogleMapReact>
  </div>
);

export default GoogleMap;
```

I have tried by setting the children as any but it didn't works.Since i am new to typescript i could not able to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

You should assign an interface to the component like such

```
interface GoogleMapProps {
   exampleprop: string
   exampleprop: number
}

const GoogleMap: React.FC<GoogleMapProps> = ({ children, ...props }) => (
  <div style={{ height: '80vh', width: '100%' }}>
    <GoogleMapReact
      bootstrapURLKeys={{
        key: environment.googleApiKey,
      }}
      {...props}
    >
      {children}
    </GoogleMapReact>
  </div>
);

export default GoogleMap;
```

The `React.FC` stands for React.FunctionalComponent. This includes the children prop and that it returns a function which returns JSX. The interface passed to `React.FC` are all the other props